# Closest approach between the JWST launch vehicle and Santa Claus's sleigh?

Tags: mission-design, james-webb-telescope, conjunction, santa-claus

[This ABC News video](https://youtu.be/5qUtBpX-gKQ?t=16) describes how for the 66th year in a row [NORAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command) will be tracking Santa Claus's progress.

This year they will have to contend with a potential conjunction between Santa's sleigh and [the Ariane 5 launch vehicle from Kourou, French Guiana on the northeastern coast of South America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) carrying the JWST to the stable manifold leading to its halo orbit around Sun-Earth L2.

**Question:** What is the expected closest approach between the launch vehicle and Santa Claus's sleigh? Is it timed so that they'll be safely separated, or could it be a close call?

Does [SOCRATES](https://celestrak.org/SOCRATES/) have any warnings?

---

[image: screenshot from the ABC News video "Gaming change for Tesla" and other news]

[image: screenshot from the ABC News video "Gaming change for Tesla" and other news]

Comment: [The AP Stylebook says to add just an apostrophe for the possessive form of a name ending in s; the Chicago Manual of Style says to add a second s as well.](https://whatis.techtarget.com/feature/Santa-Clauss-sleigh-or-Santa-Claus-sleigh) note that the launch window is fairly short and we know that Santa follows Christmas eve/very early Christmas morning around the globe, so this can easily have a fact-based answer.

Comment: Socrates might warn against drinking hemlock. Eggnog might be an appropriate substitute given the season. Either way, keep both out of reach of reindeer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There was never any chance of conjunction!

The launch happened at "lunch time" in western Europe, at about 12:20 UTC on 25-Dec-2021.

Santa would be in places where it was late at night or early morning, when all good little astronauts would be asleep, so say 24-Dec-2021 22:00 to 25-Dec-2021 04:00 local time to avoid dawn or getting too far behind schedule.

That's nearly on the other side of the globe from Europe where the launch was, but only the 00:00 to 04:00 part.

So we need to look only west by 8 to 12 hours in time zones, which starts at the western edge of North America and goes west past Polynesia.

The videos show the launch in daylight, and it travels *eastward* towards time zones later and later Christmas day.

So regardless of [altitude arguments](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57367/12102) (answer deleted at the moment) there was no chance of conjunction!

---

[image: world time zone map, cropped and annotated from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png]

cropped and annotated from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png

Answer (score 1):

By the time JWST launched, Santa should have been long since done with his errands in that part of the world. And JWST was way above Santa's track PDQ!

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot about altitude! Since Santa needs to make such a large number of descents and ascents, the ceiling will be relatively low, not to mention the need for oxygen.

Comment: But is it possible to add some facts or numbers to support this? While this is likely to be correct, Stack Exchange answers need to support their assertions through citing authoritative sources, calculations or at least a rational deduction. Perhaps a few times or altitudes is all that's necessary here. *Thanks!*