# Would the ship using the Alcubierre drive need to use conventional propulsion to move during warp? Or would the space-time "wave" push it?

Tags: engine-design, physics, alcubierre-drive, ftl

I have found various explanations on how the warp drive works. And right now I'm confused. First I thought warp drive works by expanding space-time behind you, and contracting it in front of you. I thought that this expansion creates a sort of a space-time wave that then pushes the ship like a wave, the ship itself isn't moving, so no physics laws are broken. Later I found an explanation that says that warp drive simply lowers the distance the ship has to travel, and as ***I*** understood it, it would still have to use conventional propulsion to move, but the distance it would have to cover would be much smaller. So which one of these is true? How does warp drive work, exactly? And would the ship need to use conventional propulsion to move while inside a warp bubble or not? That's the only thing I don't understand.

I know warp drive is right now only theoretical, so this is also a theoretical question.

Comment: It doesn't work. This is not even a theoretical question. It's a complete fantasy so far. For it to be a theoretical question, a working theoretical model of superluminal travel would have to exist, which it doesn't.

Comment: It works very well, thank you.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Well no, actually a viable theory exists since 1994. But that one requires exotic matter (matter with negative mass), which might or might not exist. However recently two papers came out that proposed two warp drive concepts which do not require exotic matter, and could be created with positive mass only.

Comment: "the ship itself isn't moving, so no physics laws are broken": this does nothing to address the problem of FTL travel allowing violation of causality, which only requires information to get from one point to another faster than light.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I am not sure you understood the question. Causality violation is not the problem. Space-time can move faster-than-light. Universe expands at FTL speeds, and universe is space-time with matter in it. Nothing within the universe can travel at FTL speeds, but the universe itself can, and warp drive literally makes the wave out of the universe (space-time). What I don't understand is: Does the ship need to use conventional propulsion in order to move while using warp drive.

Comment: Causality violation is absolutely the biggest problem with any form of superluminal travel or communication.

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to argue with you what or what isn't the problem. Now if you understand how the alcubierre warp drive would work, including all the recent work done on it, please explain to me why would it be the problem, because the ship is NOT moving at all, the warp bubble, which is made out of space-time which can move at any speed is. We know that because universe expands faster-than-light. And if I am not mistaken the effect of quantum entanglement also changes the particle value, or whatever, instantly no matter the distance, although we can't read the value.

Comment: @OptimusePrime have patience, this site works well and some good discussion in comments can be anticipated for this topic. I've added the `alcubierre-drive` tag to your question, click it and you can see previous questions and answers in this site on this topic. If you find something there that helps support your question you can click edit and add a reference to it within your question, e.g. "This answer notes that..." Don't worry about a few down votes, they come with the territory.

Comment: @OptimusePrime: So a scenario which requires negative mass is clearly not a viable one.

Comment: Causality violation is a problem for anything that gets information from point A to point B faster than light. Whether that involves anything "moving" faster than light is quite irrelevant. The expansion of the universe does not do this and is not a counterexample. And no, quantum entanglement does not allow superluminal communication.

Comment: Apart from that, you greatly exaggerate the status of the Alcubierre and similar "warp" drives. Positive or negative, the needed energy densities are many orders of magnitude beyond our reach, and there's strong reasons to think they wouldn't be possible even if that wasn't an issue. The answer to "how do they work" is "they probably don't".

Answer (score 2):

Warp drive or FTL works differently depending on who wrote the book. The Enterprise works differently than the Millenium Falcon. Hyperspace from Babylon 5 is different again. All of this should be in the Sci-Fi section.
--Edit: this answer was written before the question was modified to specify the Alcubierre drive. IDK if or how that works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Lol. Alcubierre warp drive theory exists since 1994 when Mexican physicist Miguel Alcubierre created a solution for Einstein field equations that could if exotic matter existed allow for ftl travel. And there have been two more papers published something like a year ago that designed a warp drive don't require exotic matter. One of them from Erik Lentz.

Comment: I referred to your answer in [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57394/12102) but alas, it's at least temporarily deleted. Please consider un-deleting? I can help add some altitudes to it and delete my comments. *Thanks!*